# Bootstrap carousel does not work with Laravel

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to show on a carousel/slider the photos related to the last 3 posts that have been made on my page.

The `$last3` variable gets the last three posts:

```
<div class="row carousel-holder">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="product carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @foreach($last3 as $post)
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../../images/Blog/{{$post->photo}}');"></div>
                    <h2><a href="post.html">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change path under style within foreach "background-image:url('../../images/Blog/{{$post->photo}}');" or change to {{ asset('images/Blog/{{$post->photo}}

Comment: It does show the slyder and on the code it get the acces to the photo, but the photos are not shown it just shows the 3 titles os the posts, i've also tryed with this and nothing

<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('{{asset('images/Blog') . '/' . $post->photo}}');"></div>

Comment: second thing  <div class="item active"> should only for first element not for rest div remove active from rest

Comment: True, that was an error there, now each slyde shows its post, but the photos still doesn't appear